# SQL Insert new columns in table B from rows of table A

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

**Input**

I have a table `Horizontal`

[image]

and another table `Vertical`

[image]

Desired output is shown in red.

The aim is that each row of table horizontal is appended as a new column of table vertical.

To be more specific:

- each row of column 'name' of table `Horizontal` will be the new column title of appended columns of table `Vertical`.
- each row of column 'value' of table `Horizontal` will be the new appended column rows of table `Vertical`.

[image]

Thus, I would like to know how to implement the desired result in SQL (I use Microsoft SQL Server).

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE HORIZONTAL 
(
    id INT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    VALUE INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO HORIZONTAL (id, name, value) 
VALUES (1, 'jersey', 22), (2, 'newYork', 33);

CREATE TABLE VERTICAL 
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PRODNAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO VERTICAL (id, prodname) 
VALUES (1, 'apple'), (2, 'orange'), (3, 'kiwi');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a great deal of sense when the values appearing at the intersections of rows and columns are just the same value duplicated into each row. *generally*, you'd be looking at `PIVOT` but as I say, I cannot make sense of the specific requirement here. Also, with an unbounded number of columns in the final result you'd also be looking to perform a *dynamic* pivot and those can be very messy. Are you sure you cannot do this better in whatever is *presenting* this data rather than trying to do it in the database?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I perfectly understand that it is not the most elegant solution. I also understand that you are confused about the requirement but my aim was to keep the users focus on the technical aspect. To answer to your question. I need to keep the solution as I described (I cannot do it in 'presenting' the data rather than trying to do it in the database). However, now according to your answer and the one of Hunt Geo it seems clear that I need to use PIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `dynamic PIVOT`

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = STUFF(
                              (SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + h.name + ']' FROM HORIZONTAL h FOR XML PATH (''))
                             ,1,1,'')
--PRINT @cols

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT id, prodname, ' + @cols + char(13) + 
                          N' FROM 
                          (   select v.*, h.name, h.value 
                             from VERTICAL v
                             CROSS JOIN dbo.HORIZONTAL h    
                          ) src
                          PIVOT
                          (
                             MIN(value) FOR name IN ('+ @cols +')
                          ) pvt'

--PRINT @query
EXEC (@query)
```

See my demo here http://rextester.com/WGUU74996

Answer (score 2):

You need first to generate each property name for each prod name using cross join, then use the `PIVOT` operator:

```
SELECT id, prodname, [jersey], [newyork]
FROM
(
    SELECT
      v.id, name, value, v.prodname
    FROM Horizontal as h
    CROSS JOIN Vertical AS v
) AS t
PIVOT
( 
  MAX(value) for name IN([jersey], [newyork])
) AS p;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52ba0/1)

```
| id | prodname | jersey | newyork |
|----|----------|--------|---------|
|  1 |    apple |     22 |      33 |
|  2 |   orange |     22 |      33 |
|  3 |     kiwi |     22 |      33 |
```

---

If you want to do this for any properties and not to list them manually, you need to do it dynamically using dynamic sql like in [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52ba0/4).

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for the answer. Sorry, in the first line do I need to specify  [jersey], [newyork] ?? The fact is that in my real data the table horizontal has much more cities and sometimes they change. Thus, I was looking for something more dynamic.

Comment: @S12000: Then why do this with SQL at all? If you want your app or Website to show the data as described, then use the programming language at hand. select from the tables and fill your grid in a loop.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I perfectely agree and understand. But I need to do everything in SQL because of many business constraints.

Comment: @S12000 , No, but in this case you have to do it dynamically, I will update my answer now.

Comment: @S12000 - See my edit, I added a dynamic demo to do it dynamically